# What are the main settings required for mysql with freeradius in operation?

Tags: mysql, freeradius

I didn't find in the technical guide of the official site specific recommendations for mysql, although I believe they vary by the number of sessions that freeradius works with.

I work in a college with about 10,000 students. Let's assume this is the maximum number of users that can login. We also use two controllers, Ruckus Zone Director and Ruckus SmartZone (we are moving to the latter in order to break up ZD)

The radius server is Slackware 14.1, with MariaDB 5, which is a big problem, as this version doesn't do transactions like transaction without locking the table. So I am urging my boss to upgrade freeradius to another Slackware 14.2 server where I can install MariaDB 10.

While it doesn't allow it, I'm trying to see what I can optimize on MariaDB 5. First, innodb_buffer_size is 826933248.

There are no serious issues with this during the day, for example, it doesn't happen that many users are out of access due to delayed request processing. But yesterday, when running a transaction to make a copy of the radacct table, it locked the table and used the entire buffer.

However, anyone who knows more reasons for giving my boss permission to update radius right away would appreciate it even more.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. For admin ones, ask at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry, but it was the freeradius website that brought me here, and the issue encompasses freeradius + mysql.

https://freeradius.org/community/#contributing

Comment: Did you at all verify, that you don't have the same issue on a newer verssion? This question attracts opinion based answers, because you are formally asking for arguments to backup your opinion against the opinion of your boss.

Comment: I talked to my boss a short time ago, and he explained certain details of why not update at the moment, basically there are other priorities that will expedite other tasks. But the main issue is summarized in the title. What I want, at least now, is to optimize what I have, that is, to optimize MariaDB 5 so that freeradius runs well. But in that regard, my boss also made it clear to me that the freeradius servant said, in response to an email, that for a company with up to 10K users, it doesn't need many settings for freeradius to work well.